# In a complex fourier series what does the term $\overline{c_n}$ stand for?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Im confused on what the bar in $\overline{c_n}$. Is $\overline{c_n}$ the conjugate of $c_n$? if not, what does the bar indicate? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $\bar{c}_n$ is the complex conjugate of the Fourier coefficient of $c_n$